# How to get rid of braces in boolean expressions with AND and OR

Tags: algorithm, scala, abstract-syntax-tree, boolean-logic, algebraic-data-types

Let`s say I have some simple boolean expression

```
(A || B) && (C || D)
```

The goal is, to get rid of braces in this expression, for example

```
(A || B) && (C || D) => A && C || A && D || B && C || B && D
```

We know that `&&` evaluates before `||` from left to right.
To achieve this I have created the following algebraic data type:

```
sealed trait Predicate
case class Or(left: Predicate, right: Predicate) extends Predicate
case class And(left: Predicate, right: Predicate) extends Predicate
case object True extends Predicate
case object False extends Predicate
```

Let`s assume that we already have some kind of string parser, which converts string to `Predicate`, it builds some kind of Abstract Syntactic Tree.
For example for expression `(true || true) && (true || true)` we will have the following tree: `And(Or(True, True), Or(True, True))`. Here we get into account the braces. We need to get `Or(Or(And(A, C), And(A, D)), Or(And(B, C), And(B,D)))`.
I stuck with the following solution:

```
def extractOr(pred: Predicate): Predicate = pred match {
    case And(Or(l, r), Or(ll, rr)) => Or(Or(And(l, ll), And(l, rr)), Or(And(r, ll), And(r, rr)))
    case And(Or(l, r), p) => Or(And(l, p), And(r, p))
    case And(p, Or(l, r)) => Or(And(p, l), And(p, r))
    case p => p
}

def popOrPredicateUp(pred: Predicate): Predicate = pred match {
    case And(l, r) => extractOr(And(popOrPredicateUp(l), popOrPredicateUp(r)))
    case Or(l, r) => Or(popOrPredicateUp(l), popOrPredicateUp(r))
    case p => p
}
```

But it works incorrect for example for this case: `And(False, Or(And(Or(True, True), False), True))`

UPD: As @coredump pointed out, I need to get [DNF(sum of products)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)

Comment: Based on your title question and the introduction, it was not clear at first whether you want to compute the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form or if  you want to refactor your code somehow. Or maybe you don't want DNF, after all. Is this homework?

Comment: @coredump : DNF(sum of products) - this exactly what I am looking for! good point.

Comment: In "And(False, Or(And(Or(True, True), False), True))" wouldn't you want that to short-circuit to False immediately, since if there is 1 False in an And it evaluates to False?

Comment: @Bobas_Pett No, I just want to create 'sum of product' without actual evaluation. In real world application instead of 'True' or 'False' I have some Boolean functions(rules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with great help @coredump(he pointed out the right direction) and Haskell package [`hatt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hatt)(particulary that [code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hatt-1.5.0.3/docs/src/Data-Logic-Propositional-NormalForms.html#toDNF)). I came to the following solution:

```
sealed trait Predicate
case class Or(left: Predicate, right: Predicate) extends Predicate
case class And(left: Predicate, right: Predicate) extends Predicate
case class Not(pred: Predicate) extends Predicate
case object True extends Predicate
case object False extends Predicate

object PredicateOps{

  def toNNF(pred: Predicate): Predicate = pred match {
    case a @ (True | False) => a
    case a @ Not( True | False) => a
    case Not(Not(p)) => p
    case And(l, r) => And(toNNF(l), toNNF(r))
    case Not(And(l, r)) => toNNF( Or(Not(l), Not(r)))
    case Or(l, r) => Or(toNNF(l), toNNF(r))
    case Not(Or(l,r)) => toNNF( And(Not(l), Not(r)))
  }

  def dist(predL: Predicate, predR: Predicate): Predicate = (predL, predR) match {
    case (Or(l, r), p) => Or(dist(l, p), dist(r, p))
    case (p, Or(l, r)) => Or(dist(p, l), dist(p, r))
    case (l, r) => And(l, r)
  }

  def toDNF(pred: Predicate): Predicate = pred match {
    case And(l, r) => dist(toDNF(l), toDNF(r))
    case Or(l, r) =>  Or(toDNF(l), toDNF(r))
    case p => p
  }

}
```

Here is how it works:

```
val expr = And(False, Or(And(Or(True, True), False), True))
val dnf = (PredicateOps.toNNF _ andThen PredicateOps.toDNF _).apply(expr)
println(dnf)
```

And the output `Or(Or(And(False,And(True,False)),And(False,And(True,False))),And(False,True))`  which is correct DNF.

Comment: DNF for any complex term can be huge.  Why don't you eliminate terms involving TRUE or FALSE, which you can evaluate, making the result smaller, as you go?  [Your example would then produce FALSE]

Comment: @IraBaxter the final goal of the solution is not to evaluate the whole statement, but to split statement into disjunctive clauses.

Comment: .  I understand that (I've built exactly such disjunction builders).  The blowup of size can be breathtaking (exponential); we found we wanted all the help we can get to manage the size.   Terms that tautological are ... useless.  This optimization won't stop you from expanding the form if it contains variables, where it contains variables.